# Vectors (calculus 3)

Tags: calculus

I was reviewing Calculus 3 for my upcoming analysis class and was looking at Vector Functions. I just have a question about this specific one for when I look at $t = 2$.

$\vec{r}(t) = \sqrt{t+2}\hat{i} + 3t\hat{j} + \frac{1}{t+1}\hat{k}$

My question is, does $\vec{r}(2) = 2\hat{i} + 6\hat{j} + \frac{1}{3}\hat{k}$ only, or is it ALSO $\vec{r}(2) = -2\hat{i} + 6\hat{j} + \frac{1}{3}\hat{k}$.

I guess the general question is, can a Vector Function give 2 different vectors for one value of the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that the expression $\sqrt{t+2}$ should also give you a $-2$ when you plug in a $2$ into the vector-valued function $\vec{r}(t)$? After all, it's not like you're taking the square root of both sides of an equation such as this one: $y^2=1-x^2\implies y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$. In this case, what you get are two independent functions.

Generally, a function for one unique input value gives you a particular output value. However, it can give you the same output value for two different input values. Long story short, if you keep plugging in the same thing into the function, you're always going to get the same result. So, the answer is no. A function can't yield two different output values for a single input value. A vector-valued function is still a function and all the rules for functions that were established in elementary mathematics still hold in calculus.